# Issue with fmod with doubles

Tags: c++, double, fmod, math.h

It would seem `fmod(x,1)` where `x` is a double gives the wrong result, as output by the line:

```
std::cout << fmod(min, 1) << "|" << fmod(max, 1) << std::endl;
```

I forgot the name for what you call this, but this is the smallest amount of code necessary to illustrate my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
const int deviation = 3;
void weightedRandomNumber(double min, double max);
int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));
    std::cout.precision(16);
    std::cout << 123.1 << "|" << 2789.3234 << std::endl;
    weightedRandomNumber(123.1, 2789.3234);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void weightedRandomNumber(double min, double max) {//inclusive
    int multiplier = 1;
    std::cout << min << "|" << max << std::endl;
    while (fmod(min, 1) > 0 || fmod(max, 1) > 0) {
        std::cout << min << "|" << max << std::endl;
        std::cout << fmod(min, 1) << "|" << fmod(max, 1) << std::endl;
        min *= 10;
        max *= 10;
        multiplier++;
    }
    std::cout << min << "|" << max << std::endl;
    std::cout << multiplier << std::endl;
}
```

The outputs I get when I run the code are as such:

```
123.1|2789.3234
123.1|2789.3234
123.1|2789.3234
0.09999999999999432|0.3234000000002197
1231|27893.234
0|0.2340000000040163
12310|278932.34
0|0.3400000000256114
123100|2789323.4
0|0.400000000372529
1231000|27893234
0|3.725290298461914e-09
12310000|278932340.0000001
0|5.960464477539063e-08
123100000|2789323400
0|4.76837158203125e-07
1231000000|27893234000
0|3.814697265625e-06
12310000000|278932340000.0001
0|6.103515625e-05
123100000000|2789323400000
0|0.00048828125
1231000000000|27893234000000
0|0.00390625
12310000000000|278932340000000
0|0.03125
123100000000000|2789323400000001
0|0.5
1231000000000000|2.7893234e+16
14
```

Other than this I don't quite know what to say, if I have missed anything necessary please comment so I can amend my question.

Comment: That code doesn't compile; if it did, it wouldn't produce the output you posted; and you haven't told us what output you expected and why.

Comment: Interesting. After I sorted out the compiler error and ran, I got almost the exact same output. This hints at your use of `rand` not working as one would expect.

Comment: Warning: `10 ^ multiplier` is 10 XOR multiplier, not 10 to the power of multiplier.

Comment: Handy reading: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: "this is the smallest amount of code necessary to illustrate my problem"? Really? I think you should have tried *harder* :-) BTW, you probably meant `SSCCE - short, self contained, correct/compilable example`.

Comment: Also you still haven't said what results you were expecting.  Nothing here seems odd to me.

Comment: @Sneftel Sorry about that I forgot to prototype the function.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah I just made them cuts, sorry about that.

Comment: @zzxyz I thought it was rather obvious 'fmod(123.1,1)' for example should be '0.1'

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `fmod`, which is giving the highest precision results it can.  The issue is with cout precision not behaving like you expect, combined with "rounding" because a double cannot store `0.1` accurately enough to represent what `cout` considers a precision of 16.

This code demonstrates the issue.  The rounding actually occurs when you assign `123.1` to a double, but because of the 3 digits to the left is not visible until it becomes a smaller number.

```
int main() {
      std::cout.precision(16);
      std::cout << (123.1L - 123L);
    }
```

output:

> 0.09999999999999432

Actually....this illustrates the problem even more succinctly:

```
int main() {
  std::cout.precision(20);
  std::cout << 123.1;
}
```

> 123.09999999999999432

Further reading from the comments on your question:
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Also, for the vast majority of scenarios, a double is more than fine.  For *accurate*, recursive math, you'd want to consider a heavy-duty math library, or even a math-specialized language.

Further further reading:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision/why_high_precision.html

Comment: Okay, but why does 123.1 convert to 123.09999999999999432 rather than 123.10000000000000000?

Comment: Answer updated.  As far as your first question, generally, you want to pick a precision the double will always be capable of storing accurately.  More generally, you just want to leave `cout` alone and let it do it's job.  (don't use `precision` unless you know how much precision you can accurately represent)

Comment: Perhaps this is an element of the problem, but even after removing 'std::cout.precision()' it is still broken, the output is merely changed. As shown here: https://pastebin.com/QXQcJsi9

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light Yes, this might be one of the rare cases where a double doesn't have enough precision to do what you're asking of it--I didn't really check the math continuing further on.  *Normally* the problem is more trivial, like an output issue or comparing .99999 to .99998 and trying to decide whether they are effectively equal for your purposes.